# PHP cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, captcha

So I was asked to add a captcha into a PHP page that someone created a long time ago. I'm terrible with PHP but I have done other programming so I've been trying to piece it together. Here's the code I've got so far, when the captcha is entered correctly everything works fine, but if it's entered incorrectly the page reloads with an error message as well as showing the correct message for an invalid entry below the error. Thanks for any advice!

The error is: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /var/www/vhosts/tinypaws.org/httpdocs/adoptapp.php:53) in /var/www/vhosts/tinypaws.org/httpdocs/adoptapp.php on line 290

Here's what I've got...

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Tinypaws Rescue &amp; Sanctuary</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
alert("We are sorry to say that someone has flooded our email with spam for ugg boots and knock off luggage.  This overloaded the system and it shut down our delivery.  We are going through each of them today 1/21/13 to answer all the legitimate applications."  + '\n' + '\n' + "Thank you and please email again for follow up.");
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<style>
<!--
A:link {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: underline}
A:visited {color:#6699CC; text-decoration: line-through}
A:active {color:#000000; text-decoration: line-through}
A:hover {color:#000000; text-decoration: underline}
-->
</style>

<body bgcolor="#336699" link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#6699CC" alink="#000000" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('button7contactrollover2.jpg','button7homerollover2.jpg','button7eventsrollover2.jpg','button7availablerollover2.jpg','button7adoptedrollover2.jpg','button7appsrollover2.jpg','button7forsalerollover2.jpg','button7donaterollover2.jpg','button7sponsorrollover2.jpg','button7flyersrollover2.jpg','button7foarollover2.jpg','button7youthvolrollover2.jpg','button7faqrollover2.jpg','button7linksrollover2.jpg')">
<p align="center"><img src="tpbanner23.jpg" width="669" height="328"></p>
<table width="91%" height="1017" border="3" align="center" bordercolorlight="#333366" bordercolordark="#FFFFFF">
  <tr> 
    <td width="2%" height="1007" valign="top"><p><a href="index.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('homeroll','','button7homerollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7home.jpg" name="homeroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="events.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('eventroll','','button7eventsrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7events.jpg" name="eventroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="contact.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('contactroll','','button7contactrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7contact.jpg" name="contactroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="surrender.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('surrenderroll','','button7surrenderrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7surrender.jpg" name="surrenderroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="available.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('availableroll','','button7availablerollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7available.jpg" name="availableroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="adopted.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('adoptroll','','button7adoptedrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7adopted.jpg" name="adoptroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="apps.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('approll','','button7appsrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7apps.jpg" name="approll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="forsale.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('saleroll','','button7forsalerollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7forsale.jpg" name="saleroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="donate.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('donateroll','','button7donaterollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7donate.jpg" name="donateroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="sponsor.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('sponsorroll','','button7sponsorrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7sponsor.jpg" name="sponsorroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="petsitting.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('petsitroll','','button7petsitrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7petsit.jpg" name="petsitroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><a href="flyers.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('flyerroll','','button7flyersrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7flyers.jpg" name="flyerroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></p>
      <p><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong><a href="fta.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('ftaroll','','button7foarollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7foa.jpg" name="ftaroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></strong></font></p>
      <p><a href="jessica.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('jessicaroll','','button7jessicarollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7jessica.jpg" name="jessicaroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></font></strong></p>
      <p><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong><a href="youthvolunteer.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('youthroll','','button7youthvolrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7youthvol.jpg" name="youthroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></strong></font></strong></font></p>
      <p><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="faq.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('faqroll','','button7faqrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7faq.jpg" name="faqroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a><strong></strong></font></strong></p>
      <p><strong><a href="links.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('linkroll','','button7linksrollover2.jpg',1)"><img src="button7links.jpg" name="linkroll" width="141" height="54" border="0"></a></strong></p></td>
    <td width="98%" height="4518" align="center" valign="top"> <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p align="center"> </p>
      <center>
      </p> 
      <table width="78%" height="139" border="0" align="center">
        <tr> 
          <td height="135"> <div align="center"> 
              <p align="center"><font color="#666699" size="4"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Please 
                fill out this application if you are interested in adopting from 
                Tinypaws Rescue &amp; Sanctuary.<strong> When you have been approved 
                for Adoption and have chosen your new family member, please print 
                and sign the <a href="AdoptionContract.jpg">Adoption Contract</a>. 
                You can mail or fax it to the available address. Please contact 
                us if you have any questions.</strong></font></strong></font></p>
              <p align="center"><font color="#666699" size="4" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3">All 
                starred (*) fields are required.</font></strong></font></p>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
      $me = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
      <form name="form1" method="post"
         action="<?php echo $me;?>">

        <p><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="3" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Date*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <input name="Date" type="text" id="Date" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Full Address*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="FullAddress" cols="50" rows="6" id="FullAddress"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <p><strong>Day Phone Number*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Phone" type="text" id="Phone" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Evening Phone Number:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Evephone" type="text" id="Evephone" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Email*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>What type of animal are you interested in adopting?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Interest" cols="50" rows="6" id="Interest"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Do you have a specific animal you would like to adopt? If so, what is the animal's name?:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Specific" cols="50" rows="6" id="Specific"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Who is adopting the animal companion?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Whoadopt" cols="50" rows="6" id="Whoadopt"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Why do you want an animal companion?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <textarea name="Whyadopt" cols="50" rows="6" id="Whyadopt"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>What traits are you looking for in an animal?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Traits" cols="50" rows="6" id="Traits"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Have you ever shared your home with an animal before?* If yes, please provide us with detals.</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Sharehome" cols="50" rows="6" id="Sharehome"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Do you still have the animal?*:</strong></p>
        <p>
          <input name="Stillhave" type="text" id="Stillhave" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>If no, what happened to it?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Happened" cols="50" rows="6" id="Happened"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>If you are a current or previus animal owner, please tell us about your animal.</strong></p>
        <p><strong>Was the animal adopted from a rescue group?* If yes, when/which group?*:</strong></p>
        <p>
          <textarea name="Rescuegroup" cols="50" rows="6" id="Rescuegroup"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>What type of litter will you use?*:</strong> </p>
        <p> 
           <input name="Litter" type="text" id="Litter" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>Who is your veterinarian?* Please provie name, address, and phone number.</strong></p>
        <p>
          <textarea name="Vet" cols="50" rows="6" id="Vet"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Will the new pet live with other animals?* If yes, please provide us with details.</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Otheranimals" type="text" id="Otheranimals" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Have you owned multiple animals at the same time before?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <textarea name="Multi" cols="50" rows="6" id="Multi"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>How do you plan to house the animal(s)?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Housing" type="text" id="Housing" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Do you currently have any other animals that the animal will interact with?* If yes, what animals?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Interactanimal" cols="50" rows="6" id="Interactanimal"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>How do you plan to supervise interactions?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Supervise" cols="50" rows="6" id="Supervise"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>How many people live in your household?* Please count adults and children seperately.</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Humancount" type="text" id="Humancount" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Ages of the children?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Childage" type="text" id="Childage" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Do the other adults agree to the adoption?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Otheradults" type="text" id="Otheradults" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Do you rent your home?* If yes, does your landlord allow pets?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Rent" type="text" id="Rent" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p> 
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>If there are children in the household, briefly describe how they will interact with the animal*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Childinteract" cols="50" rows="6" id="Childinteract"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>How do your children get along with animals?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Getalong" cols="50" rows="6" id="Getalong"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Will you supervise your children with the animal?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Childsupervise" type="text" id="Childsupervise" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>How much help do you expect in caring for the animal?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Carehelp" cols="50" rows="6" id="Carehelp"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Are you willing to do most of the work yourself?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Carework" type="text" id="Carework" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p><strong>What type of living arrangement do you plan to provide?*:</strong></p>
        <p> 
          <textarea name="Livingarrange" cols="50" rows="6" id="Livingarrange"></textarea>
          </strong></p>
       <p><strong>Tiny 
          Paws requires all adopters to sign a contract stating the following:</strong></p>
        <p><br>
          <strong>1. You will provide the animal with a balanced diet as recommended 
          by Tiny Paws.</strong></p>
        <p><strong>2. 
          You will provide veterinary care as necessary by a qualified veterinarian.</strong><p>
        <p><strong>5. 
          You will take the animal into consideration when making housing choices.</strong></p>
        <p><strong>6. 
          You will agree to be responsible for the animal for the rest of his 
          or her life.</strong></p>
        <p><strong>7. 
          You will not breed the animal and will return it to the rescue if it 
          is no longer wanted.</strong></p>
        <p><strong>8. 
          You will not have any animal surgically altered except for neutering.</strong></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Are you willing to sign such a contract?*:</strong></p>
        <p><strong> 
          <input name="Contract" type="text" id="Contract" size="50" maxlength="50">
          </strong></p></font>

          <img src="CaptchaSecurityImages.php" alt="" />
          Security Code: <input id="security_code" name="security_code" type="text" />

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
         </p>
        <p> 
          <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">
        </p></center>

      </form>
      <center>
 <?php
   } 

    else {

   session_start();
if(($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']) && (!empty($_SESSION['security_code'])) ) {

    $recipient = 'blakefinley94@gmail.com'; //help@tinypaws.org
      $subject = 'Adoption application';
      $from = stripslashes($_POST['Name']);
      $date = stripslashes($_POST['Date']);
      $fulladdress = stripslashes($_POST['FullAddress']);
      $phone = stripslashes($_POST['Phone']);
      $evephone = stripslashes($_POST['Evephone']);
      $email = stripslashes($_POST['Email']);
      $interest = stripslashes($_POST['Interest']);
      $specific = stripslashes($_POST['Specific']);
      $whoadopt = stripslashes($_POST['Whoadopt']);
      $whyadopt = stripslashes($_POST['Whyadopt']);
      $traits = stripslashes($_POST['Traits']);
      $sharehome = stripslashes($_POST['Sharehome']);
      $stillhave = stripslashes($_POST['Stillhave']);
      $happened = stripslashes($_POST['Happened']);
      $rescuegroup = stripslashes($_POST['Rescuegroup']);
      $litter = stripslashes($_POST['Litter']);
      $vet = stripslashes($_POST['Vet']);
      $otheranimals = stripslashes($_POST['Otheranimals']);
      $multi = stripslashes($_POST['Multi']);
      $housing = stripslashes($_POST['Housing']);
      $interactanimal = stripslashes($_POST['Interactanimal']);
      $supervise = stripslashes($_POST['Supervise']);
      $humancount = stripslashes($_POST['Humancount']);
      $childage = stripslashes($_POST['Childage']);
      $otheradults = stripslashes($_POST['Otheradults']);
      $rent = stripslashes($_POST['Rent']);
      $childinteract = stripslashes($_POST['Childinteract']);
      $getalong = stripslashes($_POST['Getalong']);
      $childsupervise = stripslashes($_POST['Childsupervise']);
      $carehelp = stripslashes($_POST['Carehelp']);
      $carework = stripslashes($_POST['Carework']);
      $livingarrange = stripslashes($_POST['Livingarrange']);
      $contract = stripslashes($_POST['Contract']);

      $mime_boundary = "----tiny paws----".md5(time());

        $msg .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $msg .=     "<html>".
                "<b>From:</b><br>".
                "$from<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Date:</b><br>".
                "$date<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Full Address:</b><br>".
                "$fulladdress<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Phone:</b><br>".
                "$phone<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Evening Phone:</b><br>".
                "$evephone<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Email Address:</b><br>".
                "$email<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>What type of animal are you interested in?:</b><br>".
                "$interest<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Is there a specific animal you would like to adopt? If so, what is the animal's name?:</b><br>".
                "$specific<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Who is adopting the animal companion?:</b><br>".
                "$whoadopt<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Why do you want an animal companion?:</b><br>".
                "$whyadopt<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>What traits are you looking for in an animal?:</b><br>".
                "$traits<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Have you ever shared your home with an animal before?:</b><br>".
                "$sharehome<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Do you still have the animal?:</b><br>".
                "$stillhave<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>If no, what happened to it?:</b><br>".
                "$happened<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Was the animal adopted from a rescue group?:</b><br>".
                "$rescuegroup<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>What type of litter will you use?:</b><br>".
                "$litter<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Who is your veterinarian?:</b><br>".
                "$vet<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Will the new pet live with other animals?:</b><br>".
                "$otheranimals<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Have you owned multiple animals at the same time before?:</b><br>".
                "$multi<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>How do you plan to house the animals?:</b><br>".
                "$housing<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Do you currently have any other animals that the animal will interact with?:</b><br>".
                "$interactanimal<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>How do you plan to supervise interactions?:</b><br>".
                "$supervise<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>How many people live in your household?:</b><br>".
                "$humancount<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Ages of the children?:</b><br>".
                "$childage<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Do the other adults agree to the adoption?:</b><br>".
                "$otheradults<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Do you rent your home?:</b><br>".
                "$rent<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>If there are children in the household, briefly describe how they will interact with the animal:</b><br>".
                "$childinteract<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>How do your children get along with animals?:</b><br>".
                "$getalong<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Will you supervise your children with the animal?:</b><br>".
                "$childsupervise<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>How much help do you expect in caring for the animal?:</b><br>".
                "$carehelp<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Are you willing to do most of the work yourself?:</b><br>".
                "$carework<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>What type of living arrangement do you plan to provide?:</b><br>".
                "$livingarrange<br><hr><br>".
                "<b>Are you willing to sign such a contract?:</b><br>".
                "$contract<br><hr><br></html>\n";
                $msg .= "--$mime_boundary--\n\n";

                $headers = "From: Adoption Application Page <blakefinley94@gmail.com>\n"; //help@tinypaws.org
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";

                mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $headers);

        print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=process.html">'; 

    unset($_SESSION['security_code']);
} else {
error_reporting(0);
echo "Something doesn't look right... Try entering the captcha again.";
}

    }
?> 

      </center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF">&copy;2006 Tinypaws 
Rescue &amp; Sanctuary All rights reserved.<BR>Website maintained by <a href='mailto:blakefinley94@gmail.com'>Blake Finley</a>.<BR>
    All content on this site is the property of 
Tinypaws Rescue &amp; Sanctuary. It may not be used in part or in whole without 
expressed written permission</FONT></P></ST1:PLACE></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start the session before any output has been sent to the browser. So you'll have to move the `session_start();` to the top of your file.

(That's because for starting the session the server has to sent the session cookie with the response header - and after sending some normal output (http body) headers can't be sent anymore)

Comment: Thanks!! Worked perfectly!